# Android - how add Alert Dialog incoming Call?

Tags: android, apk

I testing code from https://gist.github.com/ftvs/e61ccb039f511eb288ee and I want show an alert dialog when there is an incoming call.

This is my code (but toast working):

CallReveiver.java:

```
package com.example.arek.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Date;

public class CallReceiver extends PhonecallReceiver {
    public static String data = "";
    fetchData process;
    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
        process = new fetchData(ctx.getApplicationContext());
        process.execute();
    }
```

fetchData.java

```
package com.example.arek.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    String data = "";
    Context context;
    public fetchData(Context mContext) {
        this.context = mContext;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            [...]
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(context, this.data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //WORKING

        //Alert no wrking...
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Example message");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

If I simulate an incoming call then app is crash... Problem with context...

Please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing application requirement. Let me know when you are ready to pay me for getting you an apk directly!

Comment: I have a code but I do not know if it would be needed here :)

Answer (score 1):

THere is no way.  The app that pops those screens up is a separate application.  There's no API for adding text to it.  You could write your own dialer app, get the user to install it, and provide all the functionality the user expects.  But there's no way to inject it into their app.

Answer (score 0):

toast works

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
"Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
toast.show();
```

Comment: I am currently using TOAST, but how do I set them up for a talk time?